# Отключить http при подключении https

Tags: javascript, php, http, ssl, https

тестирую самоподписанный ssl сертификат на openserver. Вопрос в том, https работает, все хорошо, но как отключить протокол http для сайта?

Comment: вам нужно сделать перенаправление с http на https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как отключить протокол http для сайта?

Например:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Или :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPD по комменту - рабочий вариант - полностью содержимое `.htaccess` в `localhost`:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: а где это добавлять?.htaccess файла на openserver нету

Comment: В корне Вашего сайта содайте файл .htaccess и всавьте любой из вариантов, между <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> тут код </IfModule>

Comment: в папке localhost создал файл .htaccess, внутри файла написал <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>Перезапустил все, не работает. Http все равно работает=(

Comment: У Вас именно в папке localhost Ваш сайт и запускной файл - index.php находится?

Comment: да, у меня сам сайт сейчас называется  localhost

Comment: Проверил у себя - все работает, см. UPD в ответе.

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо=)

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!

Comment: Ммм, а такой вопрос, почему, если я вместо имени домена ввожу ip адрес, то http все равно работает=)

Comment: Ну, ip мало кто вводит - по нынешним временам выделенный ip не у всех стоит-  на одном ip может висеть десятки сайтов. На Ваш этот вопрос пока что не знаю ответа. Попробуйте создать отдельный вопрос - так оптимальнее можно найти знающего.

Comment: Понял,спасибо=)

Comment: >>> Пожалуйста )